# Mint: Filesystem root running out of space (but its not actually full)

Tags: linux-mint

Whenever I come back to my computer after a while, I have a popup saying something like:

**The volume "Filesystem root" has only 0 bytes disk space remaining**

With an "examine" or "ignore" button.  Sometimes the value is 0, other times it says some small non-zero number.

The problem is that my root partition should have plenty of space.  If I run df -h, I get something like this:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  768M   16M  753M   3% /run
/dev/sda6               72G   27G   41G  40% /
tmpfs                  3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb3              2.7T  1.9T  676G  75% /mnt/data
/dev/sda5              512M   24K  512M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                  768M   36K  768M   1% /run/user/1000
```

It says I have 41GB left.

How can I figure out what is happening?  The suggestions I have found so far all relate to people who are actually out of space.

Perhaps something is writing large temporary files to / and running me out of space?  If so, how do I catch it in the act and stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found my own solution: Timeshift was trying to back up bulk data from another drive and would run out of space.

I had set up an SFTP folder and because of the way it was linked, timeshift picked it up even though it usually ignored everything on the bulk data drive.

Adding the sftp directory to the exclusion list seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: For me, I had to delete 2-year old backups. No idea why they were there. Timeshift is off by about 20GB for some reason, but as long as I have space again, we're good.